# In-app purchase outside of the appstore

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I'm making an app for a certain museum. Some parts of the app should be restricted only for visitors purchasing tickets with a code printed on them.

This code can used to get access to the restricted parts of the app.

Is it something apple can reject?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way apple can reject your app. It has changed strict guidelines of its iOS developer agreement to allow in-app subscriptions outside the App Store.

The App Store Review Guidelines states the following:

> *11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app.*

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Feb 2018 version of App Store Review Guidelines 3.1.1 this is not possible for now.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase: If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game
>   currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a
>   full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may use in-app
>   purchase currencies to enable customers to “tip” digital content
>   providers in the app. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons,
>   external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to
>   purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

Comment: True, but read also section 3.1.3 Other Purchase Methods, which allows for a bunch of exceptions.