# In-App Purchase without option to purchase through app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to add an in-app purchase to one of my iPhone applications, to remove ads.  I was planning on just adding it to the app store, and not selling the IAP through my app.  All of the tutorials that I see for in-app purchases involve buying the the in-app purchase through the application.  I'd like to just check to see if the purchase was made when loading the app.  Is this possible, or do I have to provide the ability to purchase the IAP from within the app?

This is not the same question as the proposed duplicate.  I was asking if it was possible to have an IAP that I could make available through the App Store and not the App.  The suggested duplicate is titled: "In-app purchase outside of the App Store", and that's exactly opposite what I asked.

Comment: You can offer a paid version of your app that has no advertising alongside your free version, but if you want people to be able to pay to remove the ads from the free version then you need to implement in-app purchasing *in your app* - that is the *in app* bit :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-app purchase outside of the appstore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664017/in-app-purchase-outside-of-the-appstore)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  See explanation in the original post.